# Wordpress Posts Not Appearing in Search Results

Tags: wordpress, search, post

I am having a problem with my search engines including posts in the search results. I have noticed when I add a new post that it will show up in the search results just fine. However, these are older posts from an old site. I have noticed that once I edit the "published" date that they do not show up in the search results anymore. Has anyone ran into a problem similar to this that can help me out?

Comment: What is the URL structure of your posts?

Comment: Do you mean the permalinks? It's by post name

Comment: That's it, just www.domain.com/postname? And you talking about WordPress's built in search?

Comment: yes and yes. Technically I hard coded the searches in order to add custom classes instead of adding the wordpress search function. everything else shows up fine in the search results

Comment: "Technically I hard coded the searches in order to add custom classes" - are you talking about the search form, you added classes to the `<input>` elements and so on?

Comment: Yes that is correct, it is still the same form just with custom classes for styling